# Python escape special characters in sys argv

Tags: python, string, bash, command-line, argv

I have a script that takes sys.argv and the input may contain special characters (semicolon). I just need the input as string, but semicolon messes everything up..

I have:

```
def myscript(text)
    print text


a = myscript(sys.argv[1])
print a
```

I try:

```
>>  python script.py "With these words she greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days. She was, as she said, suffering" from la grippe; grippe being then a new word in St. Petersburg""
```

I get:

```
'With these words she greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days. She was, as she said, suffering'
None
bash: grippe: command not found
```

I just want to get the whole string into the script no matter what is inside it..

I tried:

```
a = myscript(repr(sys.argv[1]))
a = myscript(str(sys.argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's not a matter of python, you need to escape it in the calling shell. simply escape quotes as `\"` and semicolons as `\;`.

```
$ python testme.py "With these words she greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days. She was, as she said, suffering\" from la grippe; grippe being then a new word in St. Petersburg\""

With these words she greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days. She was, as she said, suffering" from la grippe; grippe being then a new word in St. Petersburg"
```

Comment: The input is made by users and is always different. Or maybe I don't understand something..?

Comment: a semicolon inside a quote is okay. what happened was that the first quote closed the arg, and the semicolon made the shell execute your command. how are you getting the user input?

Comment: well it's being sent from a website... I guess I can filter everything on the web-side through regex, but was wondering if there is a simpler way to do that..

Comment: would this help? `>>> re.escape('hello "world"')
'hello\\ \\"world\\"'`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a python issue, it's a **bash** issue. Bash thinks the `;` (semicolon) is separating a new bash command. You need to escape it.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks! THen is there any way to force escaping on the bash side?